# How can I pass a URL with separate display-text to Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google Sheets API lets me set values in a sheet using API method `spreadsheets.values.update`

If I pass a URL (or should that be URI?) like `http://www.example.com/123` as a cell value it displays as a link in the sheet. But in the sheet I want my link to display as [123](http://www.example.com/123) and I can't see how to encode this... and trying to Google is getting me nowhere since "URL" is used in so many places.

How should be cell text be formatted?

Comment: To create a hyperlink in a cell, you either enter the raw link, or use the Sheets [`=HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en) formula to display text that is not the raw link.

Comment: So using the API I need to actually pass `=HYPERLINK (...)` as the cell string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code should work

```
sheet.update_cell(1,2, "=HYPERLINK(\"http://www.example.com/123\",\"123\")")
```

Result is :

[image]

Comment: Great. It seems weird they don't support it as a value, only through delegating a formula, but it works :)